How to fix this python import shadowing problem?
Problem Overview
I'm facing an import shadowing problem with a python 3.12 project that uses google protobuf.
Below is the structure of my project.
Project
├── proto (generated by protoc)
│   ├── google
│   │   └── api
│   │       └── ...
│   └── my_proto (depends on google.api protos)
│       └── ...
└── main.py

Virtualenv
└── lib
    └── python3.12
        └── site-packages
            └── google
                └── protobuf

I'm using a virtual environment to manage dependencies and protoc to generate python code. The problem is that in some of the generated code proto/my_proto, it attempts to do both import google.protobuf (which is the protobuf package) and the generated proto code module import google.api.xxxx. One of the imports is guaranteed to fail because the proto/google module shadows the one in the virtual environment. How can I fix this problem?
Minimal Repro
Get the Googleapi protos
clone this repo here: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis
Create a directory with the following content
.
├── project
│   ├── proto
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __main__.py
├── proto
│   └── my_proto.proto
├── build.sh
└── pyproject.toml

__main__.py
from .proto.my_proto_pb2 import *

def main():
    pass

my_proto.proto
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

message MyMessage {
    string example = 1;
}

pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
main = "project.__main__:main"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
grpcio-tools = "1.66.1"
grpcio = "1.66.1"
protobuf = "5.27.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

build.sh
proto_folder="./proto"
google_proto_folder="<dir containg this repo: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis>"

poetry lock
poetry install
poetry run python -m grpc_tools.protoc \
    -I"$proto_folder" \
    -I"$google_proto_folder/googleapis" \
    --experimental_allow_proto3_optional \
    --python_out="./project/proto" \
    --grpc_python_out="./project/proto" \
    $google_proto_folder/googleapis/google/api/annotations.proto \
    $proto_folder/my_proto.proto

poetry install

Build and Run
change the working directory to the project root and run the following:
./build.sh
poetry run main

the following error message will be shown:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/tongweid/Documents/repos/avsim-service/_local/repro/project/project/__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .proto.my_proto_pb2 import *
  File "/home/tongweid/Documents/repos/avsim-service/_local/repro/project/project/proto/my_proto_pb2.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.api'

I suspect this is because google.protobuf shadows the generated google.api.

This shouldn't be a problem, because proto.google and google are different packages. To get the former from my_proto, you'd need from . import google, not import google. Are you actually having this issue, or just assuming you will? Are you running my_proto as a script?

Please provide a [mre].

@Blckknght I'm actually having this problem. The generated code would say, for example, from google.longrunning import operations_pb2 as google_dot_longrunning_dot_operations__pb2 and import google.protobuf at the same time.
I'm not running my_proto as a script. The entry point is main.py. I'll try to provide a minimal repro.

Updated the question with minimal repro. It may have to do with the way I build the protos.

I think it's a consequence of Python-specific behavior with protoc and the absence of Python module generation to reflect the protocol buffer packages. I scanned your issue and your approach is rational but I think you can simplify your life. In other languages, modules (or the language's equivalent) would be generated by protoc and this avoids the issue. I'd encourage you to keep 3rd-party protocol buffer sources outside of (external to) your Python project i.e. git clone the googleapis repo into a distinct folder. Use --proto_path to reflect the 3rd party libraries.

Using this approach, as long as you retain the proto package paths correctly (which you should), then you can import the Python modules without issue. In this case, Google has done the legwork for you. The googleapis repo is the definitive source of Google's gRPC service protos and a dependency for all of Google's Cloud Client libraries. So, for example you can pip install google-api-core (see google-api-core) where you will find a generated google.api.annotations_pb2.py and from google.api import annotations_pb2 etc.

You're using the wrong technique to import an adjacent package from within your existing package. In Python versions since 2.6 or so (see PEP 328), all imports are assumed to be absolute unless explicitly specified otherwise.
Rather than using google.api to refer to proto.google.api, you need to either use the full name, or an explicitly relative name, starting with a leading dot: .google.api.
Try:
from .google.api import annotations_pb2 as google_dot_api_dot_annotations__pb2

(Though, wow, that name is aweful, why are you doing that to yourself? With just from . import google.api you can then reference google.api.annotiations_pb2 directly, without needing a mangled name with loads of underscores.)

Thanks, these are all actually code generated by protoc, so I later realized this question should really be about protoc not generating the correct imports. I had to write a script to manually patch all the broken imports as a workaround.
